# What is David Lynch's obsession with stages, red curtains, and female singers?

Tags: analysis, twin-peaks, david-lynch, mulholland-drive, blue-velvet

Just finished *Mulholland Drive* again, and I noticed once again there is a [woman on a stage singing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yacsz.png) in front of a red curtain, as well as the casting scenes involving the actresses singing oldies. More examples from David Lynch's films:

- *Blue Velvet* has the woman singing 'Blue Velvet' on stage with a red curtain ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5z9R9.jpg))
- *Twin Peaks* has a few examples, including Julee Cruise singing at the Roadhouse ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Arcp0rqhDrs), [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zm3qu.png)), not to mention the Little Man in the Black Lodge/Red Room ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxTY8.png))
- *Eraserhead* has the Lady in the Radiator ([video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=awVNCIjQq1A), [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q49iV.png))

I'm probably missing a few examples but I'm wondering what the connection is (if any). Is there some metaphor I'm missing about being on stage? Does Lynch really just like female singers?

[Image gallery](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bwBNN.jpg)

Comment: when it comes to understanding Mulholland Drive, I do recommend the accepted answer here on Movies & TV StackExchange http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/365/what-is-going-on-in-mulholland-drive?rq=1

Comment: I fear this question is too broad because it asks multiple questions and thus invites multiple answers, and each can be correct. How can you then pick one?

Comment: Since the stage/curtain/singers usually appear together, I felt like their symbolism might be connected as well.

Answer (score 9):

[With regards to the curtains](https://ajak2rbsed.wordpress.com/2012/11/10/behind-the-red-curtain-surrealism-in-the-works-of-david-lynch/):

> The red curtain is a recurring symbol in Lynch’s works, having its
>   first appearance in Blue Velvet. **He has expressed his fondness of a
>   particular moment – the moment when you are sitting in a movie theatre
>   and the lights go out, the curtains open, the movie begins. And it
>   takes you to another world.** This particular moment is what has
>   inspired Lynch to use this symbol more than once.
>
> The red curtain acts as a medium, a Demiurge of sorts between the
>   real, material world and the dream world. In Twin Peaks, the Red Room,
>   with red curtain walls is the place where spirits go on their way to
>   perfection, a place halfway between both worlds where anything can
>   happen and there is no problem with time.

This Tumblr contains [a selection of (unfortunately unsourced) quotes](http://journalsoncinema.tumblr.com/post/45188557672/briliant-david-lynch-quotes):

> “Curtains are both hiding and revealing. Sometimes it’s so beautiful
>   that they’re hiding, it gets your imagination going. But in the
>   theatre, when the curtains open, you have this fantastic euphoria,
>   that you’re going to see something new, something will be revealed.”

That same quote is also posted on [this page](http://www.thecityofabsurdity.com/quotecollection/curt.html).

[In this interview](http://www.timeout.com/london/art/david-lynch-interview-there-is-something-so-incredibly-cosmically-magical-about-curtains) Lynch claims not to know the origins of his fascination:

> '**I don't know where it came from, but I love curtains.** There is
>   something so incredibly cosmically magical about curtains opening and
>   revealing a new world. It resonates on a deep level with people.'

Here's [an interpretation of the theme](http://www.zenbullets.com/britfilm/lynch/eraserhead.html) by Matt Pearson:

> The world beyond the radiator is given **a very theatrical setting; the
>   stage, the spotlight and the surrounding curtains. This idea of
>   performance recurs also**; it is a stage on which the Elephant man is
>   displayed, where Dorothy sings in Blue Velvet, and Julee Cruise in
>   Twin Peaks. When Sailor dances in Wild At Heart it is very exaggerated
>   performance, as is Lil's dance in Twin Peaks: Fire Walk With Me. The
>   curtains are a motif: the title sequence of Blue Velvet, the decor in
>   the Black Lodge (the floor design mimicking that of Henry's apartment
>   block) and the academians view of the Elephant man; silhouetted
>   through curtains. Nadine, in Twin Peaks, is obsessed with the smooth
>   running of her drapes. **The curtains also link us to night-time, when
>   most of Lynch's action is set**, especially in Eraserhead and Blue
>   Velvet. Spotlights are used to highlight certain elements of
>   mise-en-scene, with unnatural pools of light featuring strongly,
>   especially in the black and white films. These pools of light are
>   often cast by standard lamps which are compulsory furniture in Lynch's
>   world.